# What is guardian code?

Tags: java, definition

My lecturer started to refer to something called guardian code in our reading material. In case it helps, this is a Java beginners module. Here are some references to in the text.

> Since there are no mutators and therefore no mutator guardian code the guardian code is forced into the constructor (as a call to the validateDate(…) private helper method). The constructor would usually call the mutators to check initial values received as constructor parameters were valid before assigning them their respective instance variables.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks!!

Comment: I can only guess that they mean validation checks.

Comment: Note that your lecturer is (presumably) there to help you, so asking him/her to clarify would be a good approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The text refers to code that provides parameter validation, "guarding" the object from entering a bad state.

Fox example, if you are building a class with a `String` property called `serialNumber` that must be seven to nine characters long, you would add a setter like this:

```
void setSerialNumber(String sn) {
    if (sn == null || sn.length() < 7 || sn.length() > 9) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("sn");
    }
    serialNumber = sn;
}
```

`if` in the code snippet above is "guardian code". The textbook says that when the class is mutable, this guardian code goes into setters. However, when the class is immutable, you move this code into the constructor:

```
MyObject(String sn) {
    if (sn == null || sn.length() < 7 || sn.length() > 9) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("sn");
    }
    serialNumber = sn;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your lecturer likely meant **guard code**.  This adds an extra defensive layer of validation to ensure that the data you're either receiving or sending off is not invalid in any way.  In general, one writes guard code to ensure that a value that they require isn't `null` (to prevent `NullPointerException`s), or is within an expected range - although that's a broader discussion on validation.

As an example, if I were writing a method called `boolean validateDate(Date date)`, one piece of guard code I'd write is:

```
public boolean validateDate(Date date) {
    if(null == date) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Date can't be null");
    }
    // other logic to follow
}
```

Comment: "one piece of guard code I'd write is:" but you wouldn't invoke this from your constructor, would you? Without making it final or static? :)

Comment: @AndyTurner:  No, *I* wouldn't particularly invoke this from my constructor.  This was meant more as a generic example of guard code; one can adopt any style or approach they wish for guard code in their constructor.